# How do I activate launchd logging on OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, launchd, launchctl

How do I activate launchd logging on OS X 10.6?

I added a new daemon that is not starting properly (status is `1`).

I want to debug the problem but I was not able to find `launchd` logs, they are not in `/var/log/launchd.log`.

Answer (score 37):

Assuming you're trying to log your process rather than launchd itself, 
if you include the following lines in the launchd plist file:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/path/to/logfile.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/path/to/another_logfile.log</string>
```

and reload the process, any logging or printing that you have internal to your script will be captured in one of those two files whenever it is run. though rotating the files appears to be up to you.  as you might expect, if you use the same file in both instances, it will log both error and stdout to the same place.

See: [Debugging launchd Jobs section at Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ).

Comment: Thanks! This works for me in Monterey.

Answer (score 31):

I found the solution

```
 sudo launchctl log level debug
```

and after this

```
 tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

Comment: I've realized that this OS needs admin, just like anything else. Was totally looking for this after a day of screaming "WTF where is the verbose flag!"  OSX rocks, sure, but tricky to get a handle on. Thx +1

Comment: Follow up, FYI: This works with OS X 10.7.2 as well. Thanks.

Comment: I've been having issues with my Leopard servers and I thought that there was something wrong with my launchd plist (though the same plist works in Snow Leopard). I happened to stumble onto this and it works like charm :)

Comment: This no longer works since 10.10 Yosemite. launchctl version:
Darwin System Bootstrapper 2.0.0: Tue Sep  9 16:30:56 PDT 2014

Comment: @JeanMertz - any alternative?

Answer (score 25):

On OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), you can use `sudo launchctl debug <service-target> --stdout --stderr` to enable one-off logging, if you don't want to take the filesystem option suggested by @peter.

Lots of stuff is different in the current implementation of `launchctl`, and the `<service-target>` is kind of weird. For example, suppose I have a local service that I configure at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/dev.localmon.plist`, which has the "label" `dev.localmon`. Its `<service-target>` is `gui/$UID/dev.localmon`, where `$UID` is your user ID, which, since you're running this at the CLI, your shell will interpolate for you.

So supposing my `dev.localmon` service was crashing on startup (it was), I could call the following to have `launchctl` pipe the process's stdout and stderr into my shell the next time (and only the next time) the service starts:

```
sudo launchctl debug gui/$UID/dev.localmon --stdout --stderr
```

Since that hangs with the open-and-ready TTYs, go to another terminal and run:

```
launchctl start dev.localmon
# start is a legacy command and doesn't use the fancy new service-target notation
```

Then, back in the first terminal, you *should* see the output. (Oddly, it doesn't close when the service process dies, so you'll have to Ctrl-C.)

Btw, once you fix your config file with whatever PATH or environment was breaking the service before, you still have to use the old `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/dev.localmon.plist && launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/dev.localmon.plist` two-step since the documentation's purported `uncache` subcommand has the following effect:

> Command is not yet implemented.

Yay for Apple's post-Jobs release strategy: "Move fast and break things"

Comment: `sudo launchctl debug` exits with `Could not find domain for` for me

Comment: Thanks!  And Jesus MacOs sux